# OrientDB - How do I get elapsed query time in the REST with OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

How do I get elapsed query time in the REST with OrientDB? I need a json field that shows the elapsed query time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `http://localhost:2480/command/name your db/sql/explain your query`

[image]

Hope it helps.